# Return dummy value if no row present for IN Clause

Tags: sql, db2

I am using DB2 and i have a situation where i want to return dummy values if no row is present in the DB for the IDs present in IN Clause

```
SELECT A.EmpName, A.EmpId,B.Address, C.OrgCode
FROM Employee A
    join Address B on A.EmpId = B.EmpId 
    join Organization C on A.EmpId = C.EmpId
where A.SecretId in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
```

I've Employee with Secret Id 1,2,3,4 in database but not 5 but the result i need is like below

```
EmpId   EmpName Address OrgCode
  1        A      XXX     23
  2        B      YYY     44
  3        C      ZZZZ    21
  4        D      KKK     23
  5       N/A     N/A     N/A
```

I need to populate the values with some dummy values.I'm getting list of secret Ids from some other system.

Please help me achieve this.

I'm Using DB2 as my database.

Comment: Chose table aliases that make sense. E for Employee, A for Address and O for Organization!

Answer (score 1):

You need a `left join` and to start with the values that you don't have:

```
SELECT e.EmpName, el.EmpId, a.Address, o.OrgCode
FROM (SELECT 1 as EmpId FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 2 as EmpId FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 3 as EmpId FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 4 as EmpId FROM sysibm.sysdummy1 UNION ALL
      SELECT 5 as EmpId FROM sysibm.sysdummy1
     ) el LEFT JOIN
     Employee e
     ON el.EmpId = e.EmpId LEFT JOIN
     Address a 
     ON el.EmpId = a.EmpId LEFT JOIN
     Organization o
     ON el.EmpId = o.EmpId ;
```

Or use the convenient shortcut:

```
SELECT e.EmpName, el.EmpId, a.Address, o.OrgCode
FROM (VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) el(EmpId)
     Employee e
     ON el.EmpId = e.EmpId LEFT JOIN
     Address a 
     ON el.EmpId = a.EmpId LEFT JOIN
     Organization o
     ON el.EmpId = o.EmpId ;
```

Comment: I've updated my question. Sorry I could not explain it earlier.

Comment: Rather than a union of a bunch of selects, you could use 'from table(values (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) el (empid)`

Comment: @jasmeet24 . . . If you don't want `NULL` for values, then use `COALESCE()`.  I'm not sure if that's what you mean by the modification.

Comment: @GordonLinoff- I can have null values. This will work but what if i have a large amount of data. Doing VALUES (1), (2), (3), (4), (5)) el(EmpId) for every data would not be feasible i guess

Answer (score 1):

With the update it's still a left join:

```
SELECT t.EmpId, NVL(A.EmpName, 'N/A'), NVL(B.Address, 'N/A'), 
       NVL(C.OrgCode, 'N/A')
FROM TABLE(VALUES ('1'), ('2'), ('3'), ('4'), ('5')) AS t(empid)
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Employee A
        ON t.empid = A.empid
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Address B 
        ON t.EmpId = B.EmpId 
    LEFT OUTER JOIN Organization C 
        ON t.EmpId = C.EmpId
;
```

As a note, by putting the numbers in quote marks you are turning them into a string. If EmpId is a string, this is good but if it's a number then it's less efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Just try to use `LEFT JOIN` instead:

```
SELECT A.EmpName, A.EmpId,B.Address, C.OrgCode
FROM Employee A
    left join Address B on A.EmpId = B.EmpId 
    left join Organization C on A.EmpId = C.EmpId
where A.EmpId in ('1', '2', '3', '4', '5');
```

Comment: . . This will work if the ids are in `Employee`.  However, the sample results have `NULL` for `EmpName`, suggesting that the ids are not even in that table.

Comment: @apomene - I've updated my question. Sorry I could not explain it earlier.

Comment: @GordonLinoff yes you are right, looks like you say. What is clear and makes sense is the use of the `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @ecp - This will only work if i have ID 5 in db, but i'm afraid i dont have that.